# Converting value of a dictionary of lists to floats

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion

Newbie to Python here! I could really do with some help on a sentiment project I'm doing in Python.

I've build this dictionary which I'd like to use to go through comments I've scraped from a Guardian article. I want to add an extra column to the `guardian_comments` dataframe which signifies whether the value in the `sentiment_score` column is very_negative, negative, neutral, positive or very_positive:

```py
lookup_dict = {
"very_negative":[-0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6], 
"negative":[-0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1],
"neutral":[0],
"positive":[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], 
 "very_positive":[0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]}

guardian_comments['sentiment_level'] = guardian_comments['sentiment_score'].map(lambda x: lookup_dict[x])
```

However, I'm receiving a `KeyError` which I think is down to the fact the dictionary lists haven't been converted to floats. Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code fragment is far from being a useful [mcve], and seems to have little to do with converting things to floats. The keys aren't floats, so that is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you are attempting to use floats contained in the *values* as keys to lookup the corresponding *key*. If so, that isn't how you use a dictionary. You need to invert your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

`lookup_dict[x]` retrieves the entry in `lookup_dict` with key `x`.
e.g. `lookup_dict["very_negative"]` would return `[-0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6]` But `lookup_dict[-0.6]` will result in a `KeyError`.
So your lambda function does not what you think it does.

The simplest solution in my opinion would be like this:

```
lookup_dict = {
    -0.9:"very_negative",
    -0.8:"very_negative",
    -0.7:"very_negative",
    -0.6:"very_negative",
    -0.5:"negative",
    -0.4:"negative",
    -0.3:"negative",
    -0.2:"negative",
    -0.1:"negative",
    0:"neutral",
    0.1:"positive",
    0.2:"positive",
    0.3:"positive",
    0.4:"positive",
    0.5:"positive",
    0.6:"very_positive",
    0.7:"very_positive",
    0.8:"very_positive",
    0.9:"very_positive",
    1:"very_positive"
}

guardian_comments['sentiment_level'] = guardian_comments['sentiment_score'].map(lambda x: lookup_dict[x])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has resolved my question!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to maintain the current structure of your dictionary, the least confusing way to do this is to define a helper function that you can apply as lambda to your dictionary:

```
def find_level(row):
    for key, value in lookup_dict.items():
        if row['sentiment_score'] in value:
            return key

df['sentiment_level'] = df.apply(lambda row: find_level(row), axis = 1)

#output:
   sentiment_score sentiment_level
0             -0.5        negative
1              0.5        positive
2              0.6   very_positive
3             -0.2        negative
4             -0.1        negative
```